# How can I use OpenCL in my system

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opencl

I have a laptop running Ubuntu, it has a 32 Bits processor (Intel Core 2 Duo T6400 2.00GHz) and a graphics card Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller. I would like to know if I can program with OpenCL in this system. If yes what do I need?

I have been searching Google, ofcourse. I found this page:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/download-intel-opencl-sdk/

But I only found a RPM package in the Linux section. I can install it in my Ubuntu system, but the package is for a 64 bit system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you will need the following distributions:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-release-notes/

Novell* SUSE* Linux Enterprise Server 11 Service Pack 1 (64-bit version)
Red Hat* Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit version).

If you cannot change distribution, an alternate way is to use NVIDIA's CUDA SDK in emulation mode. It will be slow, but will work.

Comment: Note that that Intel OpenCL SDK will only support the CPU; it will not make use of the GPU.

Comment: Thank you. I am exploring this before I get into any real work. So CUDA in emulation mode will have to do. Again Thank you!

Comment: @Anjum Kaiser Unfortunately, since CUDA 2.3 emulation mode is not supported for CUDA, and it has never been supported for OpenCL.

Answer (score 1):

Try AMD's APP SDK ([link](http://developer.amd.com/sdks/AMDAPPSDK/Pages/default.aspx)). It has 32 bit version and runs on Intel CPUs without any problems.

Using Intel GPUs for OpenCL is impossible right now.

Answer (score 0):

Intel does not support GPU accelerated OpenCL as of now. The OpenCL SDK you linked in your question will run on your CPU. So yes, no matter what GPU you have in your system, you will be able to do OpenCL -- albeit on the CPU.

Furthermore Intel only provides an RPM. You can try to use [Alien](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto) to install it on your Ubuntu system, if you had a 64bit CPU. The only thing you could do now would be to get an NVIDIA or AMD GPU and use their OpenCL SDKs respectively. Or get a new computer with Intel CPU / and 64 bit support.